# Having multiple domains on a single hosting server

Tags: domains, godaddy, domain-registrar

Heads up: both domains are registered at GoDaddy and the shared hosting server is also at GoDaddy.

I currently have a website at `www.somesite.example`. I also have another domain name `www.mynewsite.example` that I want to have, but don't want to purchase a new hosting plan as I have plenty of space and bandwidth available on the one I currently run for `www.somesite.example`. Is there a way to use BOTH domains on the same hosting account and have a separate sites run from them, as if they are both totally separate sites?

I was thinking since `http://123.123.123.123/` is mapped to `www.somesite.example` that they would allow me to map my new domain to some folder, like `http://123.123.123.123/newsite/` to accomplish this, but can't seem to find the right options in GoDaddy to do it. Any help or correction on terminology to better Google this would be great.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

What you want is called an "add-on" domain.

From http://webnet77.com/webstuff/parked-add-on-domain.html

> ##### Add-On Domains
>
> - You have two domains `mysite.example` and `my-other-site.example`.
> - You want the two domains to be totally separate/independent websites.

Your hosting plan should allow for add-on domains, otherwise you won't be able to use your space the way you want.

Be advised that, in an add-on domain situation, most probably the sites will not be totally separate. They will look independent to the visitors, yes. But permissions, database users, filesystem rights etc. will most probably be common and they will allow the scripts of one site to read the data and scripts of the other (because they belong to the same shared hosting account - yours!). That means that if one of the sites has a security hole that allows reading or writing arbitrary files, your other site will be affected too.

Answer (score 4):

With GoDaddy, you need to make sure you have the correct level of service to allow multiple domains to one account.  GoDaddy calls the one that can handle multiples a "Deluxe" account.

[This article](http://community.godaddy.com/help/article/48) explains how to make it work.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way to achieve what you are asking is to use cPanel, it will costs a bit more but you'll find a lot of useful and easy to add options.

I was with GoDaddy for a long then I discovered that their service is slow and awful. Then I moved elsewhere, my website become faster, and I earned a lot of visits! Try a better hosting provider and use GoDaddy only to buy domains you'll have an happier life!